# nHibernate SQL Not Available error

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have the following code to execute a simple select statement.
This query fails given the "SQL Not Available" error.
This same code as a pattern works just fine in about 20 different models.
In fact if I alter the design of the view implemented in SQL to say hide the LoadID column the query fails stating "Can execute ...  ... because LoadID doesn't exist.

My problem is when this code, the hbm.xml model, and the design of the view are all aligned the ses.Query() fails stating "SQL not available"

```
var rows = ses.Query<vInventory>().Where(c => c.CustomerRecid == recid).Select(c => new vInventory()
{
    InventoryRecid = c.InventoryRecid
    , ItemID = c.ItemID
    , LoadID = c.LoadID
    , CustomerRecid = c.CustomerRecid
}).ToList();
```

This is the mapping.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true" assembly="Asmbly" namespace="Asmbly.Models">
  <class name ="vInventory" table="dbo.vInventory" dynamic-update="true">
    <cache usage="read-only"/>
    <id name="InventoryRecid" column="InventoryRecid" type="Int64">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="ItemID" />
    <property name="LoadID" />
    <property name="CustomerRecid" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Update.  I took the output of the SQL view and dumped it into a table.
Then modified the hbm.xlm to point to the table.
Now the ses.Query() works fine.  This is NOT a workable possibility.

Please comment on InventoryRecid.  In the SQL view this attribute is

`ROW_NUMBER() over (...)`

How can I get nHibernate to use this view and utilize the InventoryRecid attribute?
I will never have attempt an update to this entity.

Update #2:
I changed the hbm.xlm mapping from

```
<class name ="vInventory" table="dbo.vInventory" dynamic-update="true">
```

to

```
<class name ="vInventory" table="dbo.vInventory" dynamic-update="false">
```

recompiled and my problem is gone.

Unfortunately, I change it back to true and recompile and my problem doesn't come back.

Comment: show us your view.

Comment: it is a CPE that integrates 3 different systems.  It is over 500 lines long.  I can't do that effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a special reason you are creating new instances of `vInventory` in the `Select` method? nHibernate should already return objects of this type based on your mapping. I think it may screw up the linq provider as a constructor call can't be translated to SQL. The linq provider will handle the Select statement as if it were a normal `IEnumerable`.

Now what happens is:
nHibernate gets a query where only this: `.Where(c => c.CustomerRecid == recid)` needs to get executed. So nHibernates only queries for the IDs of the objects (because as far as nHibernate knows, it doesn't need any more properties).
Which will give you `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...` and so on.

As soon as your `Select` gets executed (not on the database) nHibernate figures it needs the rest of the properties so it queries for them one by one by their ID (not very efficient with many results). Now your using a `ROW_NUMBER` as an ID wchich can be dangerous because it only takes the current resultset into account. When querying for a single record the `ROW_NUMBER` will always be 1, so nHibernate can't find the rest of your objects anymore.

Comment: Interesting.  And I could agree.  But I can't re-write that syntax without compile errors.  How would you write it?

Comment: I think `var rows = ses.Query<vInventory>().Where(c => c.CustomerRecid == recid).ToList();` is enough to give you the result you want. But it won't be enough if you can't change you're view. Then you'll need to disable lazy loading for this type (so nHibernate will always retrieve all properties and no roundtrip is needed)

Comment: As I said I got it working with my change to the hbm.xml mapping.  But when I change it back I can't understand why it didn't quite working.  But when I implement your var rows =  .... it still seems to do what I want.  This was working at one time a month ago maybe. Then just seemed to quit.  No idea why.  But creating the list without the redundant Select() is better.  Thanks.